# time stamp showing current date of all my posts

Tags: sql, timestamp

my problem is that i have a field in novels table timestamp,on update

```
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,no,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
```

I am using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` at the time of inserting into sql but I noticed that value of all my posts showing 21-02-2014. Any help?

Comment: Which DB are you using? SQL Server,MYSQL,POSTGRES?

Comment: Can you provide few more details like what is the datatype of the field in which you are inserting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. And the statement provided by you doesn't make much sense to me. Pl elaborate clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` means that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` fields updates when the values of that field change, not when they stay same (OR) not when you update some other field(s) other than the `timestamp` field and this behavior is by design.

probably you can do something like this to update it

```
UPDATE <your_table>
SET <your_current_timestamp> = null,
WHERE <some_condition>
```